# Call certain php script function that run bash script

Tags: php, bash, shell

I have a php script (functions.inc):

```
<?php  
function exec_mount_secured_bucket(){  
exec("/ilantest/testscript.sh");  
}  
?>
```

I would like to run that function from inside the shell, normally to run the script using php i would do:
php function.inc
But I want to call a certain function from that function file.

How to do it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [command line switches](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php) for this purpose:

```
--process-end code
-E code        Run PHP code after processing all input lines
```

This should do the job:

```
php -E 'exec_mount_secured_bucket();' function.inc
```

Comment: Hi, when trying to do so, it seems that the php looking for more commends, it does respond only open a php ?

Answer (score 1):

Create a file like this:

launcher.php

```
<?php
    include 'functions.inc';
    exec_mount_secured_bucket();
```

Then in your bash script:

```
php launcher.php
```